# Sagepay Pi - Error: 3364 (Card on File is not supported for one time tokens)

Tags: php, curl, opayo

I'm currently building a payment solution that incorporate SagePay Pi to generate, and hopefully store, tokenised card details.

I have successfully created the payment flow: User Inputs Card details > tokenisation using Sagepay JS libary > Transaction Creation >  3D Secure (if required) >  Payment Settled

Although when I try and specify that a token should be saved at the transaction stage, it returns the below error:

```
[statusCode] => 3364
[statusDetail] => Card on File is not supported for one time tokens.
[transactionId] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[transactionType] => Deferred
[fiRecipient] => stdClass Object
(
)
[status] => Invalid
[http_code] => 422
[response_header] => HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

I've tried to find the cause of this error, but the documention is somewhat lacking! Has anyone else experience this error before, and found a solution?

The full payload sent to the endpoint (https://pi-test.sagepay.com/api/v1/transactions) as per the documention (https://developer.sage.com/api/payments/api/#operation/createTransaction) is:

```
[transactionType] => DEFERRED
[paymentMethod] => Array
    (
        [card] => Array
            (
                [merchantSessionKey] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                [cardIdentifier] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                [reusable] => false
                [Save] => true
            )

    )

[apply3DSecure] => Force
[applyAvsCvcCheck] => UseMSPSetting
[credentialType] => Array
    (
        [cofUsage] => First
        [initiatedType] => CIT
        [mitType] => Unscheduled
    )

[vendorTxCode] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[amount] => 2075
[currency] => GBP
[description] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[entryMethod] => Ecommerce
[customerEmail] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[strongCustomerAuthentication] => Array
    (
        [notificationURL] => http://127.0.0.1/checkout/
        [browserIP] => 127.0.0.1
        [browserAcceptHeader] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
        [browserJavascriptEnabled] => 1
        [browserJavaEnabled] => 
        [browserLanguage] => en-US
        [browserColorDepth] => 24
        [browserScreenHeight] => 1080
        [browserScreenWidth] => 1920
        [browserTZ] => 0
        [browserUserAgent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.80 Safari/537.36
        [challengeWindowSize] => FullScreen
        [transType] => GoodsAndServicePurchase
    )

[customerFirstName] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[customerLastName] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[billingAddress] => Array
    (
        [address1] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        [city] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        [postalCode] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        [country] => GB
    )

[shippingDetails] => Array
    (
        [recipientFirstName] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        [recipientLastName] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        [shippingAddress1] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        [shippingCity] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        [shippingPostalCode] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        [shippingCountry] => GB
    )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After several emails back and forth from Sagepay, the "[Save] => true" in the initial request should have been "[save] => true" (lowercase s), this is what was causing the 3364 error.

Also to enable the storing of tokenised cards, a flag needs applying to your Sagepay account, which can only be applied by Sagepay support after a phone call.

So to anyone having issues saving tokenised cards via Sagepay Pi, it's probably due to your account lacking the required flag, so try giving Sagepay a call!

Their contact details can be found here: https://www.opayo.co.uk/contact-us